# How to use 3 object points in solvePnPGeneric?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use 3 object points in  `solvePnPGeneric()` to get a list of all possible solutions.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

obj_points = np.array([[-3.07695, 21.07856, 3.97951],
 [13.66744, 19.79025, 3.94965],
 [13.84436, 19.67679, 0.76907]])

img_points = np.array([[ 654,  440 ], [1137,  660], [1114,  743]])

proj_matr = np.array([[1298.5781, 0, 960,], [0, 1301.046, 540], [0, 0, 1]])

dist = np.array([ 0.04978662, -0.13351074, -0.00004985, -0.00033355,  0.16395245])

_, rvecs, tvecs, __ = cv2.solvePnPGeneric(obj_points, img_points, proj_matr, dist, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_P3P)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
_, rvecs, tvecs, __ = cv2.solvePnPGeneric(obj_points, img_points, proj_matr, dist, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_P3P)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\solvepnp.cpp:840: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) || (npoints >= 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_SQPNP) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function 'cv::solvePnPGeneric'
```

I believe `SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE`  and `SOLVEPNP_SQPNP` only return 1 solution.

According to the [opencv docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga624af8a6641b9bdb487f63f694e8bb90):
"3 or 4 input points. Number of returned solutions can be between 0 and 4 with 3 input points."

So why cant I use 3 object points?
And what determines the number of solutions between 0 and 4 that are returned?